# Element not intractable in selenium python while filling username and password

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, web-crawler

While using the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-extentions')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.quora.com')
user = driver.find_element_by_name('email')
user.clear()
user.send_keys('username')
password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
password.clear()
password.send_keys('password')
driver.close()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated
```

I think Quora has stopped automatic interactions with the login-box. Please explain how to automatically login to Quora using selenium or any other python library.

Comment: For future reference, it's easier for people to answer the question if you include the entire error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there are multiple elements with the name `email` and `password`, instead you can select the elements using a `CSS_SELECTOR` like so:

```
user = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.regular_login [name=email]')
user.clear()
user.send_keys('username')

password = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.regular_login [name=password]')
password.clear()
password.send_keys('password')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 elements with the name email and password on the Quora login page. One is intractable and one is not.

It appears the one that is not clickable is only displayed on signup.

In order to get the correct elements for the normal login the following xpaths were working for me:

```
user = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='regular_login']//input[@name='email']")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='regular_login']//input[@name='password']")
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if your xpth is unique. You can use chropath or pagemodellor to get a unique xpath or build one on your own. Otherwise, this is straightforward solution to click

always test your xpath twice before using it so you save time before its late.
//tag[@name='somename']